# Images not displaying in Browser

Tags: html

I have a really weird problem, when I display an image in my web application it does not show, and by using firefox's 9 web developer toolbar it picks up the images as a missing image, when I mannually paste the url in the address bar the image shows up in the browser, this is an gif file

The other weird thing is when I use Firebugs Inspect element tool, the image loads when hovering over the url in Inspect element mode, but for some weird thing is it does not show in my application.

What could be the cause of this?

Code

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://mysite.com/20029118/default.htm"><img width="125" height="30" border="0" align="left" src="https://mysite.com/imgs/20032459.gif?seq=4f2a75a2" class=" uqasajhiviugcaqbcgzs"></a>
```

Comment: Could be an issue with unclosed html tags, or numerous issues. Code you post some of the related code?

Comment: My guess is, check if path/name of image is correct inside HTML, eg. `.JPG` on server, and `.jpg` in HTML

Comment: @Anicho - I've added my code in the question

Comment: @VinayakGarg - Path name is correct, all lower case

Comment: @Vinayak Garg - if Firefox can load the image in firebug the path is correct just something on the page is not allowing it to load, either jscript, site setup or html markup usually.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://mysite.com/20029118/default.htm">

    <img width="125" height="30" border="0" align="left" src="https://mysite.com/imgs/20032459.gif?seq=4f2a75a2" class=" uqasajhiviugcaqbcgzs">

</a>
```

I can see the issue instantly it's the fact that you have `https://`, this will only allow the image to load if the site has an ssl certificate applied to it. Most production or development envrionments won't have it applied to the sites because of unnesccesary costs. Change this to `http://` then let me know the result.

Two other things to try:

Remove `?seq=4f2a75a2` from image src link, this looks like it may be randomly generated

or

Ask your admin what port is open and in the src try this `src="https://mysite.com/imgs/20032459.gif?seq=4f2a75a2:XX`

Replace the `XX` with the port number provided by your admin.

Comment: Ok, valid point, but even if I call it like this /var/www/html/imgs/20032459.gif it wont show, but then I need to say that the website starts with https, since it's the only way to gain access from outsidfe the intranet

Comment: unfortunately not, since the server admin disabled it

Comment: He has disabled the use of port 80 that make no sense the link above `http://mysite.com/20029118/default.htm` would not work if he had disabled port 80 and allowed only the used of `https`. So I am wondering if by chance you can install fiddler?